# Name error when name is defined? For class project

Tags: python, nameerror

Thank you for taking time to read this. I have a project due for my Programming class by Friday. The project is basically analyzing the most popular songs around the world. The user will input W is they want to see the most popular genre worldwide and how many streams it has. My program consists of two python files, one that contains the top 10 song list, and the other where the user will input their options.
Here is my file for my top10songs:

```
def Mostpopularw(Pop):
    Pop =='Pop with 10,882,755,219 streams worldwide'
    return Pop
```

and the file for where the user will put input

```
if choice=='W':
    print(top10songs.Mostpopularw(Pop))
```

the code runs fine but when I try to enter 'W; it prints out
NameError: name 'Pop' is not defined
but I dont understand how pop is not defined? Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mya, welcome to SO. Can you please include *all* [relevant parts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, and format it in blocks with `\`\`\`` characters do the indentation is maintained

Comment: did you mean `Pop = 'Pop with 10,882,755,219 streams worldwide'` with one equal sign?

Comment: If this is your entire code, than it looks like `Pop` is only defined inside `Mostpopularw` and will not be recognized anywhere outside that function. Is there more code in your main file where you do define `Pop`?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan sorry it is my first time using this website but I think the indentations have been fixed. That is all the relevant parts of my code. I am very much a beginner so its relatively simple

Comment: @Blackgaurd I tried one equal sign and it still did not work unfortunately

Comment: @LevM. There is not much more to my code. When we had a sample question using the def functions it was this                                                                             ' ' def celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius):
    fahrenheit = (9 / 5) * celsius + 32 
    return fahrenheit 
' def fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit):
    celsius = (5 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32) 
    return celsius
so I am basically trying to get it like this since that is the only way I know how. I am also sorry that the indentation is off since this is my first time using this website so I have no idea how it works

Comment: First it's not clear what you're trying to do, the first function takes an input (Pop) and compares it with a string, throws the result away and returns the original variable. The actual error you're seeing though is probably a missing import - you need to `import top10songs` (in the module where the second code lives) would be my guess but it's hard to tell from what you've posted

Comment: Show us the whole code.  Bits and pieces aren't helpful.

Comment: With filename - i.e. paste the contents of each file into a seperate code block and tell us the names of each since as I mentioned before at least one of your issues appears to be module import related.

Comment: @JohnGordon The entire code is extremely long and wont fit since it is 78 lines and encompasses 50 song titles and multiple countries and song titles. If there is a way to add pictures on here that would be helpful

Comment: @DavidWaterworth here is my code: import top10songs
choice=input("Hello! Welcome to a program that analyzes the most popular music in the most populous countries: China, India, United States, Indonesia, and Pakistan. Please select G for the most popular by genre, S for songs with the most streams, and C for a country breakdown.")
if choice=='G':
    choicegenre=input("Would you like to see which genre is most popular worldwide or most popular genre by country? Enter W for Worldwide and C for country.")
    if choice=='W':
        print(top10songs.Mostpopularw(Pop))

Comment: I am so sorry for the lack of indentation. I have used the ''' symbols to try and indent the lines but nothing works.

Comment: Add code to the question, not as a comment. You can't properly indent code in comments.

Comment: @Mya, you don't need to add all of your code. Just re-write it into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can tell us your expected input and output, with your actual input. And we need to see how you are calling the function, and what you are doing to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you want your `Mostpopularw` function to do, so its hard for us to help you make it do that thing. The current code doesn't make much sense, as you're comparing a `Pop` argument with a constant string, and then throwing away the result of the comparison before returning the same `Pop` value.

It may be that you just want the function to `return` the string, in which case it shouldn't be an argument:

```
def Mostpopularw():
    Pop = 'Pop with 10,882,755,219 streams worldwide'  # note, one = sign here!
    return Pop
```

Now the calling code doesn't need to pass in an argument for `Pop`, which was the error you were having (you were passing in something that didn't exist).

Comment: Okay thank you so much! I understand what you are saying. Thank you!